# oracle sorting with text as number

Tags: sorting, oracle11gr2, nls-sort, nls-comp

#### My `NLS` settings:

```
NLS_SORT    POLISH
NLS_COMP    BINARY
```

#### Simple test query:

```
select * from (
  select '11117' as x from dual
  union
  select '12988' as x from dual
  union 
  select '14659' as x from dual
  union 
  select '1532' as x from dual
  union 
  select '18017' as x from dual
) order by x;
```

#### Actual result:

```
x
-----
11117
12988
14659
1532
18017
```

#### Desired result:

```
x
-----
1532
11117
12988
14659
18017
```

#### Question:

Is there a `NLS` setting that will help me achive desired result? I know I can do `order by to_number(x)` or, even better, `order by lpad(x, 5)`, but it's not good in this case - I need a system-wide solution that won't require query change.

#### What I tried:

- `order by nlssort(x, 'nls_sort=binary');`
- `alter session set nls_sort='binary';`

Comment: Why don't you remove the apostrophes?

Comment: @LajosVeres : ) Problem is that I have numbers as text in DB.

Comment: Have you tried nls_sort=binary?

Comment: Then I don't think there is any global built-in configuration for your goal...

Comment: Thanks. I think so to and SO is my last hope ; )

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a somewhat odd solution, but ...

1. Rename your TABLE_SOMETHING to TABLE_OTHER.
2. Create a view TABLE_SOMETHING on top of the TABLE_OTHER which will TO_NUMBER() the troubled string column of yours to the same column name.
3. If the table is, application-wide, being modified, then create INSTEAD OF triggers over the view TABLE_SOMETHING.
4. Recompile possibly invalidated packages.

Won't be particularly performant when it comes to modifying large quantities of records, won't allow for truncating the table, but it might solve the ordering problem.